# Determining radii of cylinder such that jacobian is of rank 1

Tags: geometry, curves, jacobian

Hello good sirs and ladies.

I'm doing a course in Geometry and I have fallen over a question I'm having quite a hard time determining exactly what to do on, The question as I'm reading it is.

*Determine for $0<a<3/2$ the points $p$ in $L$, for which the rank of the jacobimatrix $Df(p)$ is strictly less than 2.*

Let $p$ be; $$p \in L= \left \{ (x,y,z) \mid f(x,y,z)=c  \right \}$$
Where $f(x,y,z)=\left \langle  x^2+y^2+z^2, (x-\frac{1}{2} )^2 +y^2 \right \rangle $ and $c=(1,a^2)$

I've determined the jacobian to be.
$$Df(p)=\begin{bmatrix}
2x & 2y & 2z\\ 
2x-1 & 2y & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which as I've understood it means I'll have to find alle the x and y which fulfills the following
$(x-\frac{1}{2} )^2 +y^2=a^2$, with $0<a<3/2$. But which also fulfills $2x-1\propto 2x$.

But this makes me very confused, because it makes me feel like I'm going to end up guessing.
I proposed to myself that the procedure for determining $a$'s and $x$'s would be to keep y at $0$ and than to determine the $x$'s corresponding to $x^2-x=a^2-1/4$, which seems silly to me.

Please help, any advice is useful

Comment: Are you sure your Jacobian matrix is right?

Comment: I'm very sure the jacobian is supposed to be the one written, but I only realize now, that I've messed up the function. So I'll correct that immediately.

Comment: I've also found the best answer so far was to assume $z=0$, than to subtract the y component of the function from the x component. ending up with an equation.

$$x^2-(x-0.5)^2=a^2$$

from which I can assume y=0 and find the corresponding x values such that the jacobian has rank 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rank of matrix is strictly less than 2, it means it's either 1 or 0.

If it's $0$, all element in your matrix are zero. However, it can't be as it implies $2x=2x-1=0$

If it's $1$, the rows a linearly dependent $(2x,2y,2z)=k(2x-1,2y,0)$. This can only be when $y=z=0$.

Can you do the rest?

P.S. Geometrically, this is very easy question. $f(x,y,z)$ defines two level-surfaces. Since sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ has no special points, the rank of Jacobi matrix cannot be 0. It will be 1 when two surfaces: sphere and cylinder have the same tangent plane or in other words touch. Or where the line of intersection has special points. One can easily see when it happens.

[image]

Comment: For some odd reason I cannot upvote your answer, but I love your illustration, it very well pictures what happens. I did think this was what was happening. Thank you for clearifying it.